# Getting an SearchPhaseExecutionException while searching from a client node connected to ElasticSearch Cluster

Tags: exception, search, elasticsearch

I have created an ES cluster with 2 nodes. One of the nodes is configured as master node and other as client node.The master node has indexes completely built.

When I run the following on the rest client
`http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health`, 
I get the below response

```
{
    "cluster_name": "827d89539ac6ae688c1a84b9a7076b33",
    "status": "green",
    "timed_out": false,
    "number_of_nodes": 2,
    "number_of_data_nodes": 1,
    "active_primary_shards": 4,
    "active_shards": 4,
    "relocating_shards": 0,
    "initializing_shards": 0,
    "unassigned_shards": 0
}
```

Which shows that the client node has joined the cluster.

I am able search and index from the master node. But While trying to search from the client node I am getting the below exception.

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed; shardFailures {[FI4lBsqZSne3MzDY5QLDvw][rule][0]: RemoteTransportException[Failed to deserialize response of type [org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.QueryFetchSearchResult]]; nested: TransportSerializationException[Failed to deserialize response of type [org.elasticsearch.search.fetch.QueryFetchSearchResult]]; nested: IOException[Expected handle header, got [90]]; }
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.onFirstPhaseResult(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:272)
at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction$3.onFailure(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:224)
at org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$7.handleException(SearchServiceTransportAction.java:324)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:181)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleResponse(MessageChannelHandler.java:148)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:125)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Settings I have used to connect to the master node are

```
ImmutableSettings.Builder settingsBuilder = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
            //.classLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()) // set the class loader to PRAppLoader
            .put("cluster.name", "827d89539ac6ae688c1a84b9a7076b33")
            .put("node.name", "wkoduyw7hyd")
            .put("node.master", false)
            .put("node.data", false)
            .put("action.auto_create_index", false) // disable automatic index creation
            .put("script.disable_dynamic", true) // disable dynamic scripts
            .put("script.auto_reload_enabled" , false) // disable script reloading
            .put("path.data", "H:\\WorkSpace\\LunaSprintWorks_Trunc\\miniboot-embedded\\local_8084\\Tomcat\\work\\Catalina\\localhost\\prweb\\PegaSearchIndex")
            ;
    settingsBuilder.put("discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled", true);
    settingsBuilder.put("threadpool.index.size", 1);
    settingsBuilder.put("threadpool.search.size", 1);
    settingsBuilder.put("threadpool.bulk.size", 1);
    settingsBuilder.put("threadpool.suggest.size", 1);
    settingsBuilder.put("threadpool.get.size", 1);
    settingsBuilder.put("threadpool.percolate.size", 1);
    settingsBuilder.put("transport.netty.worker_count", 2);
    settingsBuilder.put("http.netty.worker_count", 1);
```

The search query I am executing in the client node works fine on the rest client.

The query I constructed from queryBuilders is

```html
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "pxRetrieveReportData",
          "default_field" : "_instancename",
          "default_operator" : "and",
          "allow_leading_wildcard" : true,
          "analyze_wildcard" : true
        }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "fquery" : {
          "query" : {
            "query_string" : {
              "query" : "NOT _isexternal:true",
              "default_field" : "_instancename",
              "default_operator" : "and",
              "allow_leading_wildcard" : true
            }
          },
          "_cache" : false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields" : "*"
}
```

Can you let me know in which scenarios do we get this exception?

I am using the same version of elasticsearch jar in both the nodes.

Comment: What version of ES is your client and what version your cluster?

Comment: Both have elasticsearch 1.0.2. version

Comment: Are you really sure? This exception indicates a version mismatch.

Comment: I figured out the issue. We have refactored one the elasticsearch libraries to have a different package name. The master node is having this jar and the client node has the standard jars downloaded from elasticsearch.org site.  Thank you Stefan for pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That exception is a sign of, possibly, using mixed Elasticsearch versions between the client and the cluster.